# PHP: Secure user authentication?

Tags: php, security, authentication

Code below checks if administrator is logged in and shows special editing boxes on website.
For that, $show_tools will be used throughout the script.

```
 if (isset($user)){
        if($user->logincheck($_SESSION["loggedin"], "users", "user_password", "user_email")){
            $show_tools = true;
        }else{
            $show_tools = false;
        }
    }
```

Is it secure to use $show_tools afterwards? 
For example:

```
<?php
  if ($show_tools){
    ?>
    <h1> Hello, administrator! </h1>
  <?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Note that rather than `if (someCondition) { $var = true; } else { $var = false; }`, you can simply do `$var = someCondition;`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question.  Are you worried that `$show_tools` might be vulnerable to a malicious attack, and have its value modified part-way through your script?

Comment: Is your PHP interpreter configured so that when you have a query like `?show_tools=1` that `$show_tools` will be `"1"`?  If not, then you had better set `$show_tools = false` even when `!isset($user)`.

Comment: thanks, you are right. what about using $show_tools variable? is it proper way of showing tools?

Comment: @Oli: What's a non-malicious attack?

Comment: @Oli yes, is that possible to hack that variable somehow? Maybe it sounds stupid but still:)

Comment: This code is gross!  It should be: `$show_tools = $user->logincheck($_SESSION["loggedin"], "users", "user_password", "user_email")`.  Having a true/false with a conditional is always a mistake.  But i have no idea what this function does so i can't tell you if its secure.

Answer (score 0):

Use of raw `$show_tools` lacks encapsulations. Everyone can overwrite it, even you by mistake, not mentioning a malicious hacker having injected code in your program. Plus you would have to make it global as your program grows. Consider the following approach:

```
function show_tools($flag = null) {
    static $value = false;
    if (is_bool($flag)) {
        // you can run other checks here too
        $value = $flag;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Usage:

```
// authenticate
show_tools(true);

if (show_tools()) { // if authenticated
    // show the tools
}

// deauthenticate
show_tools(false);
```

Functions are meant to be non-overridable, so no one can overwrite a function and alter what you do not want to be altered without your will. With this approach you're safe and secure. Without it, anything can happen:

```
<?php
$show_tools = true;
include("your_insecure_script.php");
// Cool! I can see special editing boxes!
?>
```

Comment: What is the difference between forcing `$show_tools = true;` and `show_tools(true);` in this case? I don't see any.

Comment: The difference is in the encapsulation, which is a good thing. I have updated my answer with a broadened explanation.